# How can I determine which side collision has occured from (Java)

Tags: java, collision

I have two rectangles. In my code, I can check when a collision occurs with `Rect.intersects()` method but cannot determine which side it is from. I've tried these below and it works for X-Axis but not for Y-Axis.

```
if(R1.getTranslateX() + R1.getWidth() < R2.getTranslateX() + (R2.getWidth() / 2) ) {
                //Collision from left side
            }
if(R1.getTranslateX() > R2.getTranslateX() + (R2.getWidth() / 2) ) {
                //Collision from right side
            }
if(R1.getTranslateY() + R1.getHeight() < R2.getTranslateY() + (R2.getHeight() / 2)) {
                //Collision from top side
            }
if(R1.getTranslateY() > R2.getTranslateY() + (R2.getHeight() / 2)) {
                //Collision from bottom side
            }
```

The code doesn't get past the X-Axis to check the Y-Axis side... Any ideas?

Comment: What are `getTranslateX`, `getTranslateY`?

Comment: @EugenCovaci they are basically x and y getters for coordinates.

Comment: A rectangle has 4 coordinate sets. Which one?

Comment: @EugenCovaci top left

Answer (score 0):

Left/right and top/bottom are with respect to R1. It is not possible to know for sure in all cases from which direction a collision happened without knowing the directions the objects were moving. The following would be the best way, as I see it, to detect collision direction with the information at hand. Consider the rectangle R1. We will make an estimation on how much colliding rectangles will at most intersect before the collision is detected. We'll call this margin m. Let's detect collisions following this [illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqndx.jpg). We see that the smaller the margin, the smaller the areas at the corners are in which we don't know the direction of the collision for sure. The problem with making the margin smaller is that if the rectangles intersect more than the margin allows, we don't detect the direction of the collision at all. See code below.

```
int m = [an estimate on how much the rectangles will intersect at most];  //margin

//x-direction
if(R1.getTranslateX() + m > R2.getTranslateX() + R2.getWidth()){
    //Collision from left side
}else if(R1.getTranslateX() + R1.getWidth() - m < R2.getTranslateX()){
    //Collision from right side
}

//y-direction
if(R1.getTranslateY() + m > R2.getTranslateY() + R2.getHeight()){
    //Collision from top side
}else if(R1.getTranslateY() + R1.getHeight() - m < R2.getTranslateY()){
    //Collision from bottom side
}
```

Comment: But if I'm moving downwards like this: https://imgur.com/kZCW10S , R1.X is still smaller than R2.x so the code would never reach the Y section

Comment: Well, yeah, if you use the code that way, you are correct. I don't think it's really possible to know from which direction the collision happened exactly just from the coordinates. You would need to know which way the objects were moving. Maybe you could estimate how much the rectangles will intersect at most before you register the collision and then come up with something like [this](https://imgur.com/odPp5xX) where you consider the collision happening from left if the right side of R2 is to the left of the left red line and so on (the rectangle in the image is R1). I'll update my answer.

Comment: In case anyone else faces with the same problem, the solution that worked for me is in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062833/detecting-the-direction-of-a-collision

Comment: @emir3333 That method seems like a great solve for the problem. It seems to work by checking which direction of collision requires the least amount of overlapping, which is great. Compared to my method, the need to choose an arbitary m-value goes away. It still has the same problem with the corners, where the collision direction may in some cases be unclear. It's just impossible to know the collision direction for sure in all cases without knowing the velocities. Shouldn't be too much of a problem though as the problematic areas in the corners are likely very small.